# Powershell reflection finding function

Tags: .net, powershell, reflection

```
[Windows.Forms.Form].
Assembly.GetType(
    'System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods'
).GetMethod('GetAsyncKeyState').Invoke($null,
    @(
        0x09 # Tab key code
    )
)
```

I found this code. It works. My question is how i can find where is function stored?

Image, that I want to use the `GetAsyncKeyState` method without knowing about the code above: How can I find out what type in what assembly  provides this method?

May be there is some function like:

```
function Get-win32FunctionLocation($fName){
    #...
}

Get-win32FunctionLocation 'GetAsyncKeyState'

<#Output:

    location  : [Windows.Forms.Form]
    TypeName  : System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods

#>
```

Or may be some other source of this information...

P.S.
I know about `Add-Type`, but my interest is in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate all types in all already-loaded assemblies like so:

```
$methodName = 'GetAsyncKeyState'

$appDomain   = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain
$assemblies  = $appDomain.GetAssemblies()
$allTypes    = $assemblies.GetTypes()
$allMethods  = $allTypes.GetMethods([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'Static,Instance,Public')

$targetMethods = $allMethods.Where({$_.Name -eq $methodName})
```

`$targetMethods` will now contain any public methods named `GetAsyncKeyState`

Comment: Supplement: `$targetMethod.ToString()` to see the signature or `$targetMethod.GetParameters()` to get additional information about the parameters.

Comment: That's a helpful technique in general, but note that `.GetTypes()` also includes _non-public_ types. While this is necessary in the OP's case, because the `System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods` is _private_, it's worth pointing out that relying on private types is ill-advised. Also, I've noticed that `.GetTypes()` can seemingly report types multiple times, and doesn't include _forwarded_ types; to get all distinct public ones: `[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() + $_.GetForwardedTypes() } | ? IsPublic | Sort-Object -Unique FullName, { $_.Assembly.Location }`

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal solution to this problem. Most people that rely on Win32 functions in .NET environments use [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net) to lookup functions/members, copy the C# signature and Add-Type them in PowerShell as described [here](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/).

```
$Signature = '[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name 'Win32GetAsyncKeyState' -Namespace Win32Functions #-PassThru
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 

[Win32Functions.Win32GetAsyncKeyState]::GetAsyncKeyState([Windows.Forms.Keys]::0x09) # Tab key code
```

The namespace part can be tricky because sometimes it's not just the function but also the parameter that requires us to add additional namespaces and references; sometimes those are listed on pinvoke.net sometimes not and you only find out when you invoke the function and get an error like

> The type or namespace name  'Forms' does not exist in the namespace
> 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Then, you have to look them up in the MSDN or run a web search like "`GetAsyncKeyState site:learn.microsoft.com`" to `Add-Type -AssemblyName ..` references as needed.

I think it does not get much better since Microsoft is not interested in making the Win32 more accessible; en contraire.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rethinking your approach:

- **`System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods` is a *private* type** inside the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly, so you shouldn't rely on it - there's no guarantee that it will continue to exist (or at least exist with this particular name and/or signature).
- You generally don't want to incur the overhead of loading assemblies that are *unrelated to your application's purpose*, just because they happen to contain Windows API wrapper methods.

Therefore, **consider defining your own Windows API wrapper methods via

`Add-Type -MemberDefinition`**, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406240/45375).