# What is the proper way to link powershell and System.Windows.Forms in 2024?

Tags: windows, powershell, winforms

I have tried:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
```

and

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
Add-Type -TypeDefition @"
using System.Windows.Forms;
"@
```

But the error is always the same:

```
(3,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) using System.Windows.Forms;
```

What is the proper way to reference/link `System.Windows.Forms` to powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, while there may be similar questions, there are no answers that I found which address this completely.

The way to include and reference the assembly:

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Windows.Forms' -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Windows.Forms;
"@
```

Comment: Yes, but it's important to note that you only need this if you want to ad hoc-compile _C# code_ via `Add-Type`. In order to reference WinForms types _in PowerShell code_ `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` is sufficient.

Comment: @mklement0 one day I will be able to do what I can do in C# via powershell. until then, if I get something working in VS|Rider, this unblocks copy-paste.  BUT this is opening my mind to the notion I might have been able to do a lot more directly in powershell than I did in C#.  I've been loading `User32.dll` often. In my head and on the internet generally, if you have to use `User32.dll`, you have to ad-hoc compile some C#. Is that true, or can I pull in `User32.dll` and expose those functions in powershell?

Comment: You need C# for P/Invoke declarations (primarily; there are also a few .NET types that PowerShell cannot consume directly, notably `ref struct` types such as `System.Span<T>`), but you can limit your C# code to exposing P/Invoke methods and/or PowerShell-friendly wrapper methods around them, which PowerShell can then call. Such PowerShell-friendly wrappers are most easily produced with `Add-Type -MemberDefinition`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406240/45375) for an example.